# Writing on HDFS messed the data

Tags: hive, hdfs

I was trying to save the output of a Hive query on HDFS but the data got changed. Any idea?

See below the data and the changed one.  remove the space before the file name :)

[[Correct]: i.stack.imgur.com/ DLNTT.png

[[Messed up]:  i.stack.imgur.com/ 7WIO3.png

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are importing an array into Hive which is one of the available [complex types](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/tutorial.html#Tutorial-ComplexTypes). Internally, Hive separates the elements in an array with the ASCII character 002. If you consult an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can see that this is the non printable character "start of text". It looks like your terminal does actually print the non-printable character, and by comparing the two images you can see that 002 does indeed separate every item of your array.

Similarly, Hive will separate every column in a row with ASCII 001, and it will separate map keys/values and structure fields/values with ASCII 003. These values were chosen because they are unlikely to show up in your data. If you want to change this, you can manually specify delimiters [using ROW FORMAT in you create table statement](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html). Be careful though, if you switch the collection items terminator to something like `,` then any commas in your input will look like collection terminators to Hive.

Unless you need to store the data in human readable form and are sure there is a printable character that will not collide with your terminators, I would leave them as is. If you need to read the HDFS files you can always `hadoop fs -cat /exampleWarehouseDir/exampleTable/* | tr '\002' '\t'` to display array items as separated with tabs. If you write a MapReduce or Pig job against the Hive tables, just be aware what your delimiters are. Learning how to [write](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/writing-hive-tables-mapreduce?mz=111665-bigdata) and [read](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/reading-hive-tables-mapreduce) Hive tables from MapReduce was how I learned about these terminators in first place. And if you are doing all of your processing in Hive, you shouldn't ever have to worry about what the terminators are (unless they show up in your input data).

Now this would explain why you would see ASCII 002 popping up if you were reading the file contents off of HDFS, but it looks like you are seeing it from the Hive Command Line Interface which should be aware of the collection terminators (and therefore use them to separate elements of the array instead of printing them). My best guess there is you have specified the schema wrong and the column of the table `results` is a string where you meant to make it an array. This would explain why it went ahead and printed the ASCII 002's instead of using them as collection terminators.